# Possible draw on the iPhone/iPad web page using HTML5?

Tags: html, drawing

Is it possible to draw with your finger using the iPhone or iPad in HTML5?  If the user were on a PC then the user would need to be using a mouse for the same effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Check out deviantART's new drawing tool [Muro](http://muro.deviantart.com/) for an example, and Apple's [Safari DOM Additions Reference](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariJSRef/index.html) for an overview of the API.

Comment: Cool! I've been on-and-off dA for a while, but I haven't heard of Muro.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for something along the lines of [SketchPad](http://mugtug.com/sketchpad/). It uses a `<canvas>` element in browsers that support it (and [fakes it](http://code.google.com/p/iecanvas/) in IE).